# Cancel Intent not pausing/exiting

Tags: node.js, sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on a video/audio skill that streams news depending on the device of the user.

I have been facing a problem for the last days when asking Alexa to cancel (the skill is in German), so according the documentation to test the CancelIntent it would be "alexa, abbrechen". Doing this results in 3 different cases:

1. No response and no logs from ExitHandler nor PausePlaybackHandler, nothing happens, the light circle light up then goes off.
2. It triggers the PausePlaybackHandleras I can see in the logs, but it does not pause the video/audio when it's playing
3. It triggers the ExitHandler, says the goodbye message but doesn't end session nor stop/pause the video/audio when it's played. This happens both when the video is on or off.

Another thing to mention is that when I am logging to see which intent is being triggered by "abbrechen" word, it sometimes returns CancelIntent and other times StopIntent.

Other words do work properly to pause or exit like "pause" or "verlassen", but they don't trigger PausePlaybackHandler nor ExitHandler.

Here is the code of PausePlaybackHandler and ExitHandler, I checked with the sample code provided here https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/blob/mainline/multiple-streams/lambda/src/index.js and it should be the same.

PausePlaybackHandler:

```
const PausePlaybackHandler = {
    async canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

        return  request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
                (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent' ||
                        request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent' ||
                        request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.PauseIntent');
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        console.log('pause handler:');
        console.log(request.intent.name);
        const {playbackInfo} = await handlerInput.attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes();
        globals.paused = true;
        playbackInfo.offsetInMilliseconds =  helper.getOffsetInMilliseconds(handlerInput);
        return controller.stop(handlerInput);
    },
};
```

ExitHandler:

```
const ExitHandler = {
    async canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const playbackInfo  = await handlerInput.attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes().playbackInfo;

        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        return !playbackInfo.inPlaybackSession &&
                request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
                (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent' ||
                        request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent');
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const {playbackInfo} = await handlerInput.attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes();
        const {
            playOrder,
            index
        } = playbackInfo;
        const context = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context;
        playbackInfo.inPlaybackSession = false;
        globals.unsetSlotItem = '';
        globals.selectedItem = 0;
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        console.log('exit handler:');
        console.log(request.intent.name);
        console.log('context.AudioPlayer',context.AudioPlayer.playerActivity);
        const message = messages.GOODBYE;

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                    .speak(message)
                    .getResponse();


    },
};
```

I also tried adding to the responseBuilder for the ExitHandler, it was still only reading the message but not pausing nor quitting.

```
.addAudioPlayerStopDirective()
.withShouldEndSession(true)
```